# why does is iscroll5 cause click events to be fired multiple times?

Tags: iscroll

i'm using the following

```
jquery 1.11.1
jquery.mobile 1.4.3
cordova 2.9.0
iscroll 5
```

here's my html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="listpageid">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
       some radio buttons
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
       <div data-role="content" id="scroller">
       </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

i have an ajax call that gets a bunch of data from a server. i loop thru the results and add them to the div with id="scroller"

```
var scroller = $('<div />', {id : 'scroller'}), i = 0;

$.each(resultsArr, function(key, value) {
    scroller.append(
        $('<a>', {
            id   : 'a' + (i++),
            html : value.field1 
            on   : {
                click : function() {
                    alert("you clicked on " + this.id);
                }
            }
        }),
        $('<br />'),
        $('<br />')
    );
});

$('#scroller').replaceWith(scroller);
```

this code runs whenever an ajax call fills resultsArr

this runs fine.  it displays a list and each element is clickable.

however, when i add

```
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {click:true});
```

after

```
$('#scroller').replaceWith(scroller);
```

i get bad results:

the first time the page displays and this is executed it gives me exactly what i want, a scrollable list of clickable links.

if i leave the page and navigate back clicking on every link results in 2 alerts instead of 1.

if i leave the page and navigate back a 3rd time, clicking on a link gives 3 alerts instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. 
Try setting click as false instead of true.

myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {click:false});

It worked for me. Noe it is taking only a single click.

Also try this one if the above one goes wrong.

document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);